# JsPlumb flowchart no self-connections

Tags: jsplumb

I have a problem where I'm more-or less using the jsPlumb flow-chart demo example but where there is only ever one drop target per window and there may be one or many drag targets. However I want to forbid self-connections so that a connection can be dragged from any window to any other window EXCEPT itself.

I was thinking that maybe you would use scopes but this would mean a different scope for each window which seems over the top. Does anyone have a tidy solution?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers they pointed me in the right direction. In the end used "beforeDrop" 
when binding the "connection" it was detaching the source endpoint of the window as well as the connection.

The final solution was:

```
instance.bind("beforeDrop", function (info) {
// console.log("before drop: " + info.sourceId + ", " + info.targetId);
    if (info.sourceId === info.targetId) { //source and target ID's are same
        console.log("source and target ID's are the same - self connections not allowed.")
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/connections.html#draganddrop

Preventing Loopback Connections

In vanilla jsPlumb only, you can instruct jsPlumb to prevent loopback connections without having to resort to a beforeDrop interceptor. You do this by setting allowLoopback:false on the parameters passed to the makeTarget method:

```
jsPlumb.makeTarget("foo", {
  allowLoopback:false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event to get notified whenever new connection is created. After connection creation check whether source and target of connection are same, if so detach that connection to avoid self loop. Code:

```
jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function(ci) {

            var s=ci.sourceId,c=ci.targetId;

            if( s===c ){ //source and target ID's are same
                jsPlumb.detach(ci.connection);
            }
            else{ // Keep connection if ID's are different (Do nothing)
                // console.log(s+"->"+c);
            }
        });
```

Comment: the event name is different - http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/events.html#evt-connection